# Problems with CountDownTimer and .setBackgroundColor() / .setTextColor()

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I've looked everywhere for an answer but cannot find one for my situation. I have a couple problems and also wonder how to include millisecond countdown as well. I'm trying to get a countdown timer in the format 00.00 (seconds.milliseconds). A button is used to start the timer. The times I use depend on the button pressed, 5, 10, 15, 30, or 90 seconds. I'll just says its hard coded to 5000 ms to make simpler for now.

```
long timeSecs = 5000; // really timeSecs is dynamic but for the sake of simplicity 
long countDownInterval = 1000; // this is a static value
TextView TVcountDown = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVcountDown);

public void createTimer() {

    new CountDownTimer(timeSecs, countDownInterval) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TVcountDown.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000); // error here on
//.setText unless I cast to an int, which all values are long so I'm not sure why
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            TVcountDown.setBackgroundColor(R.color.solid_red); // error here
            TVcountDown.setTextColor(R.color.white);  // error here
            TVcountDown.setText("Expired"); // it will make it here
      // It doesn't count down, just goes straight to onFinish() and displays "Expired"
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Thanks in advance. I've been beating my head against the desk for awhile now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.
For setText

```
TVcountDown.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
```

For the color

```
Resources res = getResources();
TVcountDown.setBackgroundColor(res.getcolor(R.color.solid_red));
TVcountDown.setTextColor(res.getcolor(R.color.white));
```

you should get color from the color resource before setting.

Comment: Thanks! That all worked great! However it still goes straight to the onFinish() and doesn't actually count down.

Comment: @Droidxxx Change `countDownInterval` to `10` (or more) and use `mTextView.setText(((millisUntilFinished / 10) / 100.0) + "");` to see seconds and hundredths of milliseconds.

Comment: @Sam Thanks.  Thanks to nandeesh too!

Comment: One more question. I'm trying to keep the format 00.00 so for seconds I was able to do this by    if(millisUntilFinished < 10000) {     TVcountDown.setText("0" + ((millisUntilFinished/10) /100.0));          } else
     TVcountDown.setText("" + ((millisUntilFinished/10) /100.0));      How could I track .00 to ensure that if it's 01.1 is till display 01.10?

Comment: Look at the SimpleDateFormat, `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")` and add the two digit milliseconds on to this.

Comment: @Sam Thanks, but I couldn't figure the SimpleDateFormat out even after reading about it on the android dev site. What if I just used two timers the first counts milliseconds and every 10 milliseconds the second counter "seconds" would tick. then I could add the zero if less than 10.